# transferring many parameters using the one button. Django

Tags: django, tags

How can I transfer many parameters using one button in django? For example, I have such a button:

```
<a class="btn-link" href="/product/parameter={{ parameter_here }}" value="a">submit</a>
```

In my view I get access to it through:

```
parameter = request.GET['parameter']
```

But when I try to transfer a lot of parameters, using

```
parameter={{ product.name }}/parameter_1={{ product.price }}/parameter_2={{ product.time }}
```

and I get accesses it in the view, I receive something like that:

```
name/price/product
```

Although I'm trying to get only the first parameter `(parameter = request.GET['parameter'])`

Is there a way to pass many parameters and get access to them as in the case of one parameter (or I have to filter it out in the view)? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code would *not* work as you describe. In order for parameters to be accessible in `request.GET`, you need to pass them in the querystring:

```
a href="/product/?parameter={{ parameter_here }}"
```

Note the `?`.

To pass multiple parameters the same way, separate them with `&`:

```
a href="/product/?parameter={{ product.name }}&parameter_1={{ product.price }}&parameter_2={{ product.time }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You must format your link using `&` as separator between parameters. E.g. `param1=<value>&param2=<value2>&param3=<value3>...` in your case `parameter={{ product.name }}&parameter_1={{ product.price }}&parameter_2={{ product.time }}`, so in your view you can access them in this way

```
parameter = request.GET['parameter']
parameter_1 = request.GET['parameter_1']
parameter_2 = request.GET['parameter_2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass as many query parameters as you want [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/snippet/2016/08/22/dealing-with-querystring-parameters.html)